# How to hold access_token in sencha touch client application

Tags: web-services, security, authentication, sencha-touch, oauth-2.0

I have a sencha touch client application and restful web service with OAuth2 authorization protocol. I want to know , how I can hold access_token in my client application for further using. Now, I use a global variable to hold token, is it the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use a [Store](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) to save the data and keep it in localStorage or sessionStorage.
Store is a good tool and keep the code clean.

**Update**

Best pratices are about maintainability (legible code), efficiency, dependability, usability. So if you a framework the best pratice is use its tools. With that any programmer that have knowledge about it will understand the code faster.

With [store](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) you can keep data even in [localSession](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) or [sessionStore](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) so you have full control how long you want to save the data.

Other advantage with store you can keep multiple user or agroup multiple data with it without have to do a lot of work (like profile or other data you need to save).

Sure, you can use your global variable without problem. But in my personal opnion if you use a framework use the tools.

Comment: yes, I know about stores, but I want to know which is the best practice to hold access token (in memory using global variables, or to store in local storage)? Can you say me what is sessionStorage?